# Excel Power Query Conditional Replace Based on Another Column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

I am trying to replace the values of cells in a column only when another columns cells equal false. I am using power query from an access db so the data is bound to change regualrly when reloaded so it cant be as simple filter the column, change the other column cells, remove the filter. Below is an example of the columns in question:

Example of what I am trying to do but in power query editor to allow it replace values even when reloaded:

1. Whilst a filter to only show Requried is applied to column M, Filter Column N to only show FALSE and change this value to Outstanding (copy it down to the remaining rows)
2. Remove filter from Column N & M
3. Column M – Apply filter to just show Required
4. Column N – Apply filter to just show TRUE and change this value to Received (copy it down to the remaining rows).

Any ideas as to what could help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start table:

[image]

End Table:

[image]

Just one line of code for the replace:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCkotLM0sSk1R0lEqKSpNVYrVQRFLS8wphgj65ZcoYFOMJg7VEAsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [M = _t, N = _t]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,each [N] ,each if [M] = "Required" and [N]= "false" then "Outstanding " else if [M] = "Required" and [N]= "true" then "Received" else  [N],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"N"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: What M code changes would I have to make to my code sorry?

Comment: You just need this line.  #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,each [N] ,each if [M] = "Required" and [N]= "false" then "Outstanding " else if [M] = "Required" and [N]= "true" then "Received  " else  [N],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"N"})